# Does scapy works on macOS without problems?

Tags: scapy

I have the following output on macOS. It keeps on printing dots. Does anybody know how to check what is wrong?

```
>>> a, b = sr(IP(dst="www.target.com")/TCP(sport=[RandShort()]*10))
Begin emission:
.........Finished sending 10 packets.
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Comment: Open up wireshark on your end and see if you can see anything off. This code works fine for me on Windows.

Comment: I used tcpdump and sees nothing. But it can capture packets from the ping program.

Comment: I see that if I turn off VPN, scapy works. How to make scapy work with VPN on?

Comment: This might be a good question if you add more detail about what traffic you do see with tcpdump/wireshark, how you've set up your VPN, what you've tried so far, etc. There's an edit button at the end of the question. "Why doesn't it work" type questions with limited info are difficult to answer.

Comment: The problem is: does scapy supposed to work most of VPNs on Mac? If it doesn’t, the any VPN could be a target for testing. I don’t know details of VPN, I don’t know what specifics are relevant.